# Blocking ports with iptables 1.4.2

Tags: linux, iptables, port, uclinux

I am trying to block some ports on an embeded uClinux· The Iptables version is 1.4.2. 
The command I used was

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

But it seems that iptables 1.4.2 is not supporting `--dport`
The result of command is

```
iptables: No chain/taget/match by that name
```

If I am removing `--dport 22` from command then the rule will be added without problem and I can see it with `iptables -L`.
I wonder if --dport was supported by iptables 1.4.2. If not then is there a way to block ports in version 1.4.2. 
Another questions is where I can find manuals for old versions of iptables. 
My last questions is if there is a way to have iptables rules persistent without using `iptables-persistent`. It is possible to write a script to be run  when system is starting but I thought maybe there is a configuration file that we can write permanent rules inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the right module was not loaded. xt-tcpudp should be loaded with

```
insmod xt-tcpudp
```

to be able to add rules containing `--dport` and `--sport`